# Share TextToSpeech without saving it

Tags: android, caching, audio, text-to-speech

I would like to know how to share a TextToSpeech object using an Intent.

I already read how to convert and save the file in the internal storage using the method "synthesizeToFile()" however I need to share it without saving it in the storage of the phone.

So this makes doubt about the possibility of:

1. Is there any way to share it through, for example, WhatsApp, converting it to variable RAW or another kind of object?
2. Is it possible to use the method "synthesizeToFile()" to save it as an mp3 file in the caché memory?